# Ruby Sinatra and JSON objects from toodledo API 2.0

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

I have a small problem with receiving JSON objects. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and my goal is to receive my tasks from an API via [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) and print them more or less pretty onto the page.

I created a route `/test`:

```
get '/test' do
   json_ip_url = "http://api.toodledo.com/2/tasks/get.php?key=198196ae24792467eec09ac2191*****;modafter=1234567890;fields=folder,star,priority"
   ip_details = RestClient.get(json_ip_url)
   test = JSON.pretty_generate(ip_details) # => throws exception
end
```

The `JSON#pretty_generate` line throws an error, "only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed". What am I doing wrong here?

Update:

I'am now able to output via pretty_generate, but what do I have to do, to get the elements of it. Here is the JSON Data, it seems to me its an Array with Objects inside of it?

```
[{"num":"18","total":"18"},{"id":"11980343","title":"Add some items to your todo list","modified":1391670256,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"0"},{"id":"11980345","title":"Visit the Settings section and configure your account","modified":1391670256,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"0"},{"id":"11980347","title":"Watch our tutorial videos in the Help section","modified":1391670256,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"1"},{"id":"12607789","title":"test","modified":1392285802,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"0"},{"id":"12636039","title":"My Task","modified":1392308705,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"0"},{"id":"12636041","title":"Another","modified":1392308705,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"1"},{"id":"12636143","title":"My Task","modified":1392308789,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"0"},{"id":"12636145","title":"Another","modified":1392308789,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"1"},{"id":"12636449","title":"My Task","modified":1392308950,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"0"},{"id":"12636451","title":"Another","modified":1392308950,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"1"},{"id":"12636621","title":"My Task","modified":1392309061,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"0"},{"id":"12636623","title":"Another","modified":1392309061,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"1"},{"id":"12636665","title":"My Task","modified":1392309085,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"0"},{"id":"12636667","title":"Another","modified":1392309085,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"1"},{"id":"12636733","title":"My Task","modified":1392309137,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"0"},{"id":"12636735","title":"Another","modified":1392309137,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"1"},{"id":"12637135","title":"My Task","modified":1392309501,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"0"},{"id":"12637137","title":"Another","modified":1392309501,"completed":0,"folder":"0","star":"1"}]
```

The Code I used for pretty_generate:

```
     get '/save' do
   jdata = params[:data]
   response = RestClient.get 'http://api.toodledo.com/2/tasks/get.php?key=da21e24e2a00ba9d45008974aed00***;modafter=1234567890;fields=folder,star,priority', {:accept => :json}
    test = JSON.parse(response)
    test.to_json
     output = JSON.pretty_generate(test)
    puts output
```

Answer (score 0):

`RestClient#get` returns the raw response as a string (and not a hash or array) when called without a block, so `ip_details` isn't a structure that `JSON#pretty_generate` knows how to handle. You need to use `JSON#parse` to turn the response into a hash or array first.

Comment: Thank you, but to be honest, I dont know if I get you right, I need RestClient#get to receive my data, and if I try to parse it with JSON#parse I get another error `code`NoMethodError at /test 

undefined method `bytesize' for {"num"=>"18", "total"=>"18"}:Hash

Comment: Maybe there is there another way of getting the Data from the API? As you said RestClient returns raw response, is there an alternative? Thank you for helping!

Comment: @user3306721 edit your question and put the modified code and the error message (and please format them accordingly)